# How to get to the mobile App builder page on Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I'm new to Bluemix but I've seen on several videos some folks easily using Bluemix to create their app screen just dropping whatever they find useful on it. But I logged on and I looked everywhere for this page and I can't find it. Does anyone knows how to get there?[This image shows the place where I want to go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nCOA.png).

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile App Builder is no longer integrated into the Bluemix Developer Experience. It's been replaced with [starter apps that allow users to get started quickly integrating Watson and other Bluemix services into their projects](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/developer/create-project/).

If you would like access to the legacy App Builder tools, they are available [here](https://studio.buildup.io/home/news).

Comment: Hey Joe! Thank you so much, you really helped me! Have a nice one!